# Open Seadragon: Download currently displayed image in Viewer

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm using Open Seadragon and loaded multiple images into the viewer with

```
tileSources: ['http://url.com',
              'http://url.com',
             'http://url.com',],
```

The files that I linked in tileSources are all json but I want to download a jpg image.
How can create a function that downloads the currently viewed image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the exact view that's in the viewer at this moment? If so, you can copy the contents of the HTML canvas at `viewer.drawer.canvas`.

You might also check out https://github.com/KTGLeiden/Openseadragon-screenshot.

If you want the full high-resolution version of the image (not just what's in the viewer at the moment), I'm not aware of anything that does that.

Comment: The second one, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

You said you wanted the full high-resolution version of the image.  I would suggest looking at the "Dezoomify" browser extensions for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/dezoomify/) and Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dezoomify/iapjjopjejpelnfdonefbffahmcndfbm/related?hl=en).  I am not a web developer but I came across these browser extensions when I wanted to download a zoomable image that was created using the Open Seadragon library.  It would have been nice if there had been a button on the site to download / generate the full resolution image but now that I am aware of the Dezoomify browser extension I feel like my problem is solved.